# UV Unwrap Dirty - How to fix?

Tags: mesh, uv, normal-map

When I use smart UV unwrap in Blender for a cube with 6 sides, each side's mesh in the UV map is messed up and broken uneven. How do I fix this?

My concern is because when I bake the mesh, I get these weird black spots on the maps, is this because of the original UV map or something else?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Smart project works for a lot of things, but it's not perfect. For more complex things (such as your mesh), you will have to unwrap manually in order to have full control. Place seams as necessary to define the "chunks" you want to keep together.

Comment: Do you know if the black spots on the baked maps are because of the UV map or something else?

Comment: Not sure. Lots can go wrong during the bake process. It could be the result of some overlap - maybe try increasing your island margins slightly?

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try!